# Firestore write functions taking too long when using for-loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

**I am running a for-loop function to create/add new documents to existing collection within Firestore from iOS app.** Although I am only creating about 48 documents, which is much lower than stated write limit (500 documents per second) based on the documentation - https://firebase.google.cn/docs/firestore/quotas?hl=en&authuser=0

**My documents are simply just text, strings, pre-populated timestamps, integers and etc, there are no videos or picture files. However, just creating/add 50 documents take about 9-10 seconds from Xcode simulator.** Fortunately, the read/get operations to retrieve existing documents from Firestore is almost instantenous for 50 documents.

Below is a simple snapshot of my raw data, which I push from googlesheet to Firestore and they are really not that heavy in terms of fields and values.

[image]

**Is this something that is normal? or is it that my swift code were not "optimized"? '**

With advice from @Joakim Danielson, I tried to ADD/CREATE smaller number of documents to the Firestore, **but the latency or the creation rate stayed about the same where each document took about 0.2 seconds to be created.**

I am getting quite worried for the user experience of the app although it is only once that such creation process take place for a new user, I foresee larger number of documents being created a new user. Please review my code below and let me konw if there is any other best practice I can utilize.

Below is a screenshot of the Xcode console for reference on the time the documents get created.

[image]

```
func createAndReadUserSpecificDayProgramDataToFirestore() {
        print("codementor: createAndReadUserSpecificDayProgramDataToFirestore started")
        let tabbar = tabBarController as! MainTabBarController
        
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            print("no current user logged in")
            return
        }
        
        print("create user specific dayprogram profile using for loop and dayprogram list in tabbar")
        
        if tabbar.dayProgramList.count == 0 {
            
            print("tabbar day program list has no day program profile")
            return
        }
        
        startActivityIndicator()

        for dayprogram in tabbar.dayProgramList {
            
            print("dayprogram forloop executed")
            
            var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
            print("codementor: document is adding")
            ref = self.db.collection("Day").addDocument(data: [
                "author_uid": dayprogram.author_uid ?? "",
                "barbellWeight": dayprogram.barbellWeight ?? "",
                "benchWeight": dayprogram.benchWeight ?? "",
                "createDate": dayprogram.createDate ?? Date(),
                "dayId": dayprogram.dayId ?? "",
                "dayIntensity": dayprogram.dayIntensity ?? "",
                "daySequence": dayprogram.daySequence ?? "",
                "deadliftWeight": dayprogram.deadliftWeight ?? "",
                "defaultRestTime": dayprogram.defaultRestTime ?? "",
                "isPublicFlag": dayprogram.isPublicFlag ?? "",
                "lastUpdatedBy": dayprogram.lastUpdatedBy ?? "",
                "numberOfExercise": dayprogram.numberOfExercise ?? "",
                "overheadWeight": dayprogram.overheadWeight ?? "",
                "prcntComplete": dayprogram.prcntComplete ?? "",
                "squatWeight": dayprogram.squatWeight ?? "",
                "status": dayprogram.status ?? "",
                "targetRestEndHR": dayprogram.targetRestEndHR ?? "",
                "workoutDate": dayprogram.workoutDate ?? "",
                "workoutId": dayprogram.workoutId ?? "",
                "userID": userID
            ], completion: { err in
                
                self.programCount += 1
                
                if self.programCount == tabbar.dayProgramList.count {
                    print("dayprogram forloop function, which is to create user specific profile completed at \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())")
                    self.createAndOrReadUserSpecificDayProgramData()
                    self.stopActivityIndicator()
                    print("forlopp dayprogram all calls finished")
                }

                if let err = err {
                    print("Error adding user specific dayprogram profile: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("timestamp successfully adding: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())")
                    print("User specific dayprogram profile added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                }
                print("forlopp dayprogram \(ref!.documentID) finished")
                
            })

           print("forlopp dayprogram `dispatchGroup.leave()` was here, but this was the wrong place")
        }
        
        print("forlopp dayprogram more exucution if there was any")
        
    }
```

Comment: Have you done any measurements to determine what it is that takes so much time?

Comment: what can I measure other than the time taken for each documents to be created and the entire list of documents to be created? not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Well you only told us about the total time so that is why I asked.

Comment: each document takes about 0.1? 0.2 seconds to be created. I used my stop watch to measure...instead of using the date function within simulator. Each document get created sequentially, one after another...not sure why this is so slow when it's just a document with text, strings, etc...

Comment: Just added some Xcode log to demonstrate that it takes about 1 second for 4~5 documents to be created...which is surprisingly slow. What if I want to create over 400 documents...user might need to wait for more than 1 minute.

Comment: You can use CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() for more precise measurements.

Comment: I would investigate if it could be a problem with to many dispatch group tasks, try to measure only the Firestore execution time, send smaller number of docs and measure if the time increase seems to be linear.

Comment: Sure, updated query with CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), and I see that it takes about 0.2 seconds to create each document. I also read documents and articles saying that it could be that it takes time for my simulator device to receive that message. Let me try to remove dispatchGroup and check.

Comment: Updated the code with a different approach and also the screenshot, not using DispatchGroup, but there is no change in performance. Would appreciate advice & experience sharing on if this performance is normal or exceptionally slow.

Comment: adding smaller set of documents also resulted in similar latency where it took about 0.2 seconds on rough average to create/add each documents. I think it must be the data or the Xcode simulator. Is this normal? is firestore usually this slow?

Comment: Firebase uses its own threading system so its probably waiting after each write to perform another one. Consider using `batch = db.batch()` `batch.setData()` `batch.delete()` etc to perform multiple writes in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using batches instead of uploading individual documents

```
func createAndReadUserSpecificDayProgramDataToFirestore() {
    print("codementor: createAndReadUserSpecificDayProgramDataToFirestore started")
    let tabbar = tabBarController as! MainTabBarController
    
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        print("no current user logged in")
        return
    }
    
    print("create user specific dayprogram profile using for loop and dayprogram list in tabbar")
    
    if tabbar.dayProgramList.count == 0 {
        print("tabbar day program list has no day program profile")
        return
    }
    
    startActivityIndicator()
    let batch = db.batch()
    for dayprogram in tabbar.dayProgramList {
        print("dayprogram forloop executed")
        var ref: DocumentReference = db.collection("myCollection").document()
        batch.setData([
            "author_uid": dayprogram.author_uid ?? "",
            "barbellWeight": dayprogram.barbellWeight ?? "",
            // your data
            "workoutId": dayprogram.workoutId ?? "",
            "userID": userID
        ], forDocument: ref)
        self.programCount += 1
    }
    // this writes everything to the database all at once.
    // if ANY of them fail, an error will be thrown
    // and the entire operation fails
    batch.commit { err in
        if self.programCount == tabbar.dayProgramList.count {
            print("dayprogram forloop function, which is to create user specific profile completed at \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())")
            self.createAndOrReadUserSpecificDayProgramData()
            self.stopActivityIndicator()
            print("forlopp dayprogram all calls finished")
        }
    }
    print("forlopp dayprogram more exucution if there was any")
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tadreik, you were right, using batch() writes greatly reduced the duration taken, to less than 0.0001 seconds. Firestore performance is pretty amazing. I don't know how to thank you further.